# Android: is correcting Lint warnings useful or not?

Tags: android, seo, android-lint

I have built and published my app on Google Play and everything works fine. But I am wondering how I can improve my visibility on the market, how to appear on the first page...

So here is my question,

**Do I have to correct every little bug that appears in the Lint Warnings panel (in Eclipse) to be in a better position or is it useless?**

I have been looking for resources about that on the web, but I can't find  really interesting ones. Do you guys know a good blog that explains how to appear first on the market (or at least, not on the 1234555... page)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides advertising, there are a few useful advices about "how to get your application featured" on [this page](http://www.marketandroidapps.com/advertising/how-to-get-your-application-featured-on-android-market/), basically you have to make a flawless, polished application, which uses a lot of Google API features and is popular among users.

Correcting Lint warnings is good, because it makes your application more stable, but does not directly affect your Market visibility.

If you need more resources, search Google for "getting featured on android market", it might help.

Answer (score 3):

Correcting Lint warnings will make you a better programmer.  That's not useless.